# Binance API Python Invalid API-KEY

Tags: python, binance

Всем привет! Зашел я на [testnet Binance futures](https://testnet.binancefuture.com/en/futures/BTCUSDT), нашел свои API ключи и написал код:

```
from binance.client import Client
from binance.exceptions import BinanceAPIException, BinanceOrderException
try:
    buy_order = client.create_test_order(symbol='ETHUSDT', side='BUY', type='MARKET', quantity=1)
except BinanceAPIException as e:
    print(e)
except BinanceOrderException as e:
    print(e)
```

Код выдал ошибку:

> APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action.

При этом никаких настроек доступа к IP и API нет, просто внизу страницы плашка с ключами.
И я не понимаю в чем ошибка, использовал много вариантов, включая binance-futures-connector с предложенным на странице документации кодом, но ошибка всё та же. Молюсь о помощи!

Comment: а где вы подключились по ключу?